# Point symmetries about lines in 2D

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Say I have a 2D point `(a,b)` and a line defined as `y = mx + c` (any alternative parameterization is fine). I would like to find the point that is symemtric to `(a,b)` w.r.t. to the this line.

Are there any libraries in Python that can help with this type of transformations?

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser Good catch. No. I updated it.

Comment: This is C++ but I'm sure you can translate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65503/point-reflection-over-a-line

Comment: Hmmm ... This question doesn't appear to be on-topic for this site as it is currently being asked.  The question at it's core is a question about _math_ (not programming) and at the end it turns into a python question by _asking for an off-site resource/library_.

Comment: homework: the equation of the line passing through `(a,b)`, perpendicular to the given line is `y=1/m*(x-a)+b`. Calculate the intersection point between the lines, and get the symmetric point with respect to the intersection. Then post the solution below. (yes, handle the case `m=0` separately..)

Comment: Too bad it's been closed... If you define your line by a point `line_pt` and a vector `line_vec`, and your point is `pt`, with numpy you can do: `pt_proj = np.dot(pt - line_pt, line_vec) * line_vec / np.dot(line_vec, line_vec); pt_norm = pt - line_pt - pt_proj` and then the symmetrical point is `pt_sym = pt - 2*pt_norm`.

Comment: @Jaime then reword the question to ask for a solution instead of a library, and then request to re-open